# Python NameError:

Tags: python, class

I am new to learning `Python` and currently I am working on Classes. Below is a program that I am referring to. However, on calling the class, I am getting the following error:

```
from airtravel import *

a = Aircraft("G-EUPT", "Airbus A319", num_rows=22, num_seats_per_row=6)
```

**Error message:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Aircraft' is not defined
```

**Code:**

```
class Flight:

    def __init__(self, number):
        if not number[:2].isalpha():
            raise ValueError("No airline code in '{}'".format(number))

        if not number[:2].isupper():
            raise ValueError("Invalid route number '{}'".format(number))

        if not (number[2:].isdigit() and int(number[2:]) <= 9999):
            raise ValueError("Invalid route number '{}'".format(number))

        self._number = number

    def number(self):
        return self._number

    def airline(self):
        return self._number[:2]


class Aircraft:

    def __init__(self, registration, model, num_rows, num_seats_per_row):
        self._registration = registration
        self._model = model
        self._num_rows = num_rows
        self._num_seats_per_row = num_seats_per_row

    def registration(self):
        return self._registration

    def model(self):
        return self._model

    def seating_plan(self):
        return(range(1, self._num_rows + 1),
                "ABCDEFGHJK"[:self._num_seats_per_row])
```

Where am I going wrong? Kindly help me understand. Why am I receiving this error?

I plan to execute the command `a.Registration` to get `G-EUPT` as the output.

Comment: Code looks fine to me. Where are you calling the Aircraft class? Same path as of class one or any other path?

Comment: If you change `from airtravel import *` to `from airtravel import Aircraft`, you might get more information about what is going wrong.

Comment: Is that *all* the code? Is the code actually in a file named `airtravel.py` (or in `airtravel/__init__.py`)? An easy way this would break is if the code defined `__all__` and neglected to include `"Aircraft"` in `__all__`. As @Shadow says, `from airtravel import Aircraft` will tell you if it exists in the module you're importing (and will also bypass any `__all__` caused problems, and is generally considered better style, as it makes it explicit what you need).

Comment: `line 1` is where the error is, but the code shown would be on line 3...

Comment: I guess this is just a file path issue, not more than that.

Comment: @BhushanPant I did not understand what you meant by same path. If you are asking about individual files being in the same location, then yes. Both the `Aircraft` and `Flight` classes are there in the same module called `airtravel.py`.

Comment: @Shadow The following is the error I get upon doing `from airtravel import Aircraft` -> `>>> from airtravel import Aircraft
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'Aircraft'
>>>
`

Answer (score -1):

this is a basic question in python for the new ,the python searchs for file path,
I guess the **airtravel** is that you create .PY(**airtravel.py**) file in your folder
like this:
[image: in the same file folder]

and you will get the answer:
[image: the answer]

and if you learn more about **import** python file ,you can look here.
[the import in python](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/import.html)

Answer (score -2):

```
from airtravel import (Aircraft, Flight)
```

Comment: The brackets you have there aren't necessary - in fact I didn't even know that was valid.

Comment: 1. sorry but the question is too simple, so no explanation. Besides, the code line is also self-explanatory.
2. Brackets are not necessary but valid